# UIGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail scenarios

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I'm writing a multitouch gesture recognition library for non-iOS platform, but UIGestureRecognition and all that concept seems pretty solid, so in some way I use it as a reference.

One thing is unclear for me: the requireGestureRecognizerToFail method. Can anyone point on some any potential use-cases other then double-triple-n-tap over single tap? I do understand it's purpose and even wrote that kind of implementation, but eventually removed this thing entirely. Because IMHO the code smells a bit (if you try to include it in base gesture recognition class, even though it works perfectly with doubletap-tap scenario). For me it seems much cleaner to have an extra couple lines of code to workaround single-doubletap situation (once you actually have it), rather then include this very specific thing into base gesture class... But maybe I miss some other scenarios? Have you met any?

---

OK, so I accidently found another use-case: Swipe on UIScrollView (swipe pan gesture recognizer requires swipe to fail) developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=104 min30.

Was my question so unclear, or here's not many i-developers?